# Add Structural Block - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

i have a problem with structural block in magento 1.9.
This is my local.xml layout file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="pluma" as="pluma" template="pluma/helloworld/simple_page.html"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This is my 1column.phtml template file:

```
    <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices'); ?>

    <pre><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pluma'); ?></pre>

    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
```

And this is my template file (very simple):

```
<h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference!</h1>
```

Magento response only "empty"  tags. I don't understand my error..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: In code you didn't close `<layout />` node. Make sure it closed

Comment: Thanks for response programmer_rkt, I just add tag in local.xml but doesn't works. I have this issue only on magento 1.9

Comment: did layout node  close there ?

Comment: Otherwise your code seems ok to me. Also before testing, you need to disable cache and Remove all existing cache in `var/cache`. Then refresh any page

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to remove all cache and disable it but nothing.. :( is responsive theme "the problem"? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try checking the log files
http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-error-logs/

Comment: Hello check added template into your applied theme

Comment: @RaffaeleCapasso What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have a custom phtml file loaded for a particular page ( let's say home)? I can provide you code for that. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .phtml (default template files for magento) file instead of .html :

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="pluma" as="pluma" template="pluma/helloworld/simple_page.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Also make sure you change the name in pluma/helloworld :  simple_page.html -> simple_page.phtml